# I am getting invalid type ( struct ) error while interacting with the solidity smart contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js, merkle-tree

Here is the Error Message:

**Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid type (argument="type", value="Proof", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)**

Here is the solidity function

```
function createOffer(
        address _requestorAddress,
        address[] memory _requestedNftAddress,
        uint[] memory _requestedNftId,
        address[] memory _offeredNftAddress,
        uint[] memory _offeredNftId,
        Proof[] memory _proofsRequested,
        Proof[] memory _proofsOffered
)
```

Here is the struct

```
    struct Proof {
        address nftAddress;
        bytes32[] proof;
    }
```

here is the typescript code

```
    const tx = await contractWithSigner.createOffer(
        address,
        [counter_party_nfts_addresses[0]],
        [counter_party_nft_ids[0]],
        [my_nft_addresses[0]],
        [my_nft_ids[0]],
        [
            [
                counter_party_nfts_addresses[0],
                getMerkelProof(counter_party_nfts_addresses).proof,
            ],
        ],
        [[my_nft_addresses[0], getMerkelProof(my_nft_addresses).proof]]
    );
```

and here is the getMerkleProof function:

```
    const getMerkelProof = (addresses: string[]) => {
        const leaf = keccak256(addresses[0]);
        const leaves = addresses.map((x: any) => keccak256(x));
        const tree = new MerkleTree(leaves, keccak256, { sortPairs: true });
        const proof = tree.getProof(leaf, 0);
        const root = tree.getRoot().toString("hex");
        return {
            proof,
            root,
        };
    };
```

As the struct accepts two arguments 1 nftAddress and 2nd is merkleProof,
i.e

```
[[address,proof]]
```

but unable to find the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Proof[] memory _proofsRequested,
    Proof[] memory _proofsOffered
```

argument types should be array of Proof structs but you are passing array of arrays

```
      [
        [
            counter_party_nfts_addresses[0],
            getMerkelProof(counter_party_nfts_addresses).proof,
        ],
    ],
    [[my_nft_addresses[0], getMerkelProof(my_nft_addresses).proof]]
```

instead

```
    [// convert the inner array to obj
        {
            nftAddress: counter_party_nfts_addresses[0],
            proof    :getMerkelProof(counter_party_nfts_addresses).proof,
        {,
    ],
    [ 
        {
         address: my_nft_addresses[0], 
         proof: getMerkelProof(my_nft_addresses).proof
        }
    ]
```

Comment: getting the same error, as solidity accepts structs as arrays, it doesn't accept objects as structs.

Comment: @RashidIqbal can you test that this `getMerkelProof ` function is working. make sure it is not returning undefined

Comment: [
    {
      "address": "0x495f947276749ce646f68ac8c248420045cb7b5e",
      "proof": [
        {
          "type": "Buffer",
          "data": [
            72, 178, 31, 128, 233, 81, 177, 228, 155, 130, 135, 232, 190, 120,
            79, 146, 228, 92, 216, 159, 81, 118, 182, 194, 223, 27, 99, 79, 235,
            186, 231, 221
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

Comment: type of proof is wrong. it should be ` bytes32[] proof` but it is array of objects

Comment: with hex/bytes32, throws the same error
  [
    {
      "address": "0x495f947276749ce646f68ac8c248420045cb7b5e",
      "proof": [
        "0x48b21f80e951b1e49b8287e8be784f92e45cd89f5176b6c2df1b634febbae7dd",
        "0xeed331fcd5c14f4608a3669e26bd157c45e8b40a2d5ea24c74330773f43c157a",
        "0x7dd8bfdbbb7a9c98c2a2dd4d9f70e2047eab5c562fc1882c0e676d15d7cc098e",
        "0xbd1dfdf5e8a6ea0a3704e159e412027749820a60910af232a172b4d870c10b36",
        "0x7dd8bfdbbb7a9c98c2a2dd4d9f70e2047eab5c562fc1882c0e676d15d7cc098e"
      ]
    }
  ]